# Javascript bitwise operation

Tags: javascript

I was doing a Leetcode problem for [231. Power of Two](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/) and one of the solution is to use Bitwise Operators to get the Rightmost 1-bit, here is the answer.

```
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) return false;
    const x = n;
    return (x & (-x)) === x;
};
```

But when i tested it with input `-2147483648`, the function return wrong answer but it is good for Python for exemple.

It is because of some problems with Javascript to deal with signed integer?

Thanks for your response.

Edit:
Oups, i ignore the fact that power of two couldn't be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just use `n > 0` and simultaneously couple our two statements here.

This'll get accepted in JavaScript:

```js
const isPowerOfTwo = function(n) {
  return n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) === 0;
};

console.log(isPowerOfTwo(-2147483648))
```

Python doesn't have that integer overflow.

```
class Solution:
    def isPowerOfTwo(self, n):
        if n < 1:
            return False
        while not n & 1:
            n >>= 1

        return n == 1
```

We can also simply `return false` if `n < 1` first. Here are implementations of the same idea in Java/C++:

#### Java

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        while ((n & 1) == 0) {
            n >>= 1;
        }

        return n == 1;
    }
}
```

#### C++

```
static const struct  Solution {
    static const bool isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        while (!(n & 1)) {
            n >>= 1;
        }

        return n == 1;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for all negative integer the result is wrong because of the sign.
This format stores numbers in 64 bits, where the number (the fraction) is stored in bits 0 to 51, the exponent in bits 52 to 62, and the sign in bit 63.
For more information look https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp